# How to repeat an input until given suitable answer?

Tags: python

I have finished a code, so that it asks the user to answer an arithmetic question and tell them if their answer is correct or not and so on.... I started doing some tests and realised if user enters anything then a number is gives me an error.
My Code:

```
import random

    name=input("Welcome to this Arithmetic quiz,please enter your name:")

    score = 0

    for i in range(10):

          number1=random.randint(20,50)

          number2=random.randint(1,20)

          oper=random.choice('+-*')

          correct_answer = eval(str(number1)+oper+str(number2))

          answer = (int(input('What is:'+str(number1)+oper+str(number2)+'=')) == correct_answer)

          if answer:
                  print('Correct!')

                  score += 1

          else:
                  print('Incorrect!')

    print(name,"You got",score,"out of 10")

    if score>1 and score<=3 :
                  print('Practice More!')

    elif score>4 and score<=7 :
                  print('You did well!')

    elif score>7 and score<=9 :
                  print('Excellent!')

    elif score==10 :
                  print('You are a Genius!')

    else:
                  print('Have you tried your best?')
```

I want to know how do I repeat line 9 until the user enters a number?
THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE BECUASE I WANT THE USER TO SPECIFICALLY ENTER A NUMBER. IF HE/SHE DID IT WILL TELL THEM IT IS WRONG OR RIGHT AND MOVE ON TO THE NEXT QUESTION.

Comment: You may use `isnumeric()` as condition of a `while` loop to check, if the input only contains numbers.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do that ?

Comment: Of course, just use `while not string.isnumeric():` as the loop and inside of it set `string = input('Provide a number: ')`. Here `string` has to be present before and must not be a number already.

Comment: it says string is not defined

Comment: Split your `answer=` line into collecting the input (within the `while` loop where `answer` replaces `string` in my example) and evaluating the correct answer after the loop, when the user entered a valid number. Also set `answer=""` before the loop. So repeat the input until the user provides a number and compare to `correct_answer` afterwards.

Comment: can you just edit my code please.

Comment: Please take a look here: https://codeshare.io/RQ3kM

Comment: OMGG !!!! I love u man (no homo) , I really appreciate your answer , thank you 100 times :)

Comment: Glad, that it works. The linked duplicate provides good hints as well concerning validating inputs.

Comment: quick question is 'answer.isnumeric()' a function ?

Comment: It is a [method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#unicode.isnumeric) for unicode strings. You could use `'test'.isnumeric()` as well, which returns `False` - in this case `answer` was the string.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting the for loop in a while loop until true then exit the loop.  Did that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for reply, but that means the user will just keep on going until he gets it right which is not fair , I only need it to repeat if the user does not enter a number , is that possible ?